# Running argon2-browser with vite and vue

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vite, webassembly

I've spent a few hours trying to run `argon2-browser` lib in a Vue app with Vite.

I think I've done everything just how the docs told me to do, but I keep getting the error:

```
This require call is not allowed because the imported file "vite-plugin-wasm-namespace:\\node_modules\\argon2-browser\\dist\\argon2.wasm" contains a top-level await
```

My `vite.config.ts`:

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    wasm(),
    topLevelAwait(), 
    vue(),
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": fileURLToPath(new URL("./src", import.meta.url)),
      "/^~/": '',
    },
  },
  optimizeDeps: {},
});
```

I've tried changing the plugin's order, but it doesn't help.

I'm importing lib this way `import argon2 from 'argon2-browser'`.

[Argon2 lib link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/argon2-browser)

If I remove `topLevelAwait()` plugin - the error is not changing. If I remove `wasm()` plugin I get the error that wasm is not supported:

```
"ESM integration proposal for Wasm" is not supported currently. Use vite-plugin-wasm or other community plugins to handle this. Alternatively, you can use `.wasm?init` or `.wasm?url`. See https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#webassembly for more details.
```

If anybody has any ideas on how can I fix that please let me know! I'm willing to provide additional context and/or details if needed as well.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you need to configure Vite to allow top-level await on wasm files.

Comment: @DaniloFagundes yes, that's why I'm using the plugin, but seems like it just doesn't work.

Comment: I am in doubt if it will work, but try the code that I will put

Answer (score 1):

This was pretty confusing, and I don't know exactly how this works. But ultimately I got it working with some very simple code. Seems like the trick is to use the bundled version instead of the regular one.

```
npm i argon2-browser
```

```
import argon2 from "argon2-browser/dist/argon2-bundled.min.js";
console.log(argon2.hash); // prints: function hash(B)
```

Note that there was no need for the packages `vite-plugin-wasm` or `vite-plugin-top-level-await`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, see if it helps you with the solution

```
import argon2Wasm from 'argon2-browser/dist/argon2.wasm';
 
async function instantiateArgon2() {
  const argon2 = await WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming(fetch(argon2Wasm), {
    env: {
      memoryBase: 0,
      tableBase: 0,
      memory: new WebAssembly.Memory({ initial: 256 }),
      table: new WebAssembly.Table({ initial: 0, element: 'anyfunc' }),
      __memory_base: 0,
      __table_base: 0,
    },
  });

  return argon2.instance.exports;
}

const argon2 = await instantiateArgon2();
console.log(argon2); // exemplo de uso
```

Comment: Outputs an error `[plugin:vite:import-analysis] Failed to resolve import "a" from "node_modules\argon2-browser\dist\argon2.wasm". Does the file exist?`